# unable to run python script from Batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, notepad++

Hello I Wish to run a python script, *(I did not write)*, from a batch file I wrote.

I have 2 questions:

1. Running the command in the Command prompt works fine but from the batch file it fails with no error message; the python script creates an output file but it is not created when running through the batch file.

   ```
   @echo off
   SET /P PrePRD=Enter the Pre Production file name: 
   SET /P PostPRD=Enter the Post Production file name: 
   Set /p IdColumn= Enter the Name of the ID column (ID - Original Input):

   cmd /k "cd /d C:\CSVComparison"
   C:\CSVComparison\csv_diff.py -src "%PrePRD%" -dest "%PostPRD%" -keys "%IdColumn%"
   ```
2. I wish to open the output file which python created using `Notepad++`, but I'm not sure it will work this way:

   ```
   start C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe C:\CSVComparison\results_details.json
   notepad++.exe C:\CSVComparison\results_details.json
   ```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you start another instance with `cmd /k`, but the following command gets executed in the original instance (I guess, you want it to be executed in the second instance). Either execute it in the original instance (no `cmd /...` at all; you might need to `call` it)

```
pushd "C:\CSVComparison"
call "C:\CSVComparison\csv_diff.py" -src "%PrePRD%" -dest "%PostPRD%" -keys "%IdColumn%"
popd
```

or `start` it in another window:

```
start /d "C:\CSVComparison" "csv_diff" "C:\CSVComparison\csv_diff.py" -src "%PrePRD%" -dest "%PostPRD%" -keys "%IdColumn%"
```

2) if a folder or file contains space(s) , you need to enclose the whole thing in quotes. Better: get used to always enclose folders/filenames in quotes:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\CSVComparison\results_details.json"
```

(`start`) takes the first quoted string as window title, so you need to give it a fake title (`""`)

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question - unfortunately Windows does (yet?) not know about [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), so you need to specify that you want to run your python script using python interpeter:

```
cmd /k "cd /d C:\CSVComparison"
C:\path\to\python.exe C:\CSVComparison\csv_diff.py -src "%PrePRD%" -dest "%PostPRD%" -keys "%IdColumn%"
```